# Gnome-Shell 3.10.4 on screen keyboard can't type when prompt appears

Tags: gnome, keyboard, accessibility, onscreen-keyboard

When using the out of box on-screen keyboard in Gnome-Shell 3.10.4, and a prompt appears, such as entering the root password for gksudo; the on-screen keyboard is behind the prompt and I cannot type on the on-screen keyboard.

How can I go about fixing this? Should I use onboard instead?

Comment: Nevermind, the same issue occurs with onboard too. The prompt that appears is too greedy and doesn't let any background applications to have access.

Answer (score 2):

I used gksu-properties to change the "Grab mode" to disable.

simply type:

```
gksu-properties
```

in a terminal or run dialogue box.

This changes weather the screen is "grabbed" or not while entering the password. Disabling this allows other applications to eavesdrop, a security vulnerability. But insistently it allows other applications to input to the password field, useful for on-screen keyboard and scripts. You can switch between the modes by setting "Grab mode" to prompt, as the setting suggests you will be greeted by a prompt before your able to enter your password.

I'd like to point out that most of us enter passwords in the terminal without grabbing anything, this presumably has the same security vulnerability as using gksudo without grab. The "secure keyboard" option found in xterm by holding down ctrl and Left Clicking then selecting "secure keyboard" has what seems to be the same function as grab.